# How to save one VC's text field data to another VC's table view?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a `tableView` in my first view controller which has parsed local JSON data in their rows. Also, I have a `UIViewController` in my second view controller which has 6 textFields and save button. I want to save textFields data to my first view controller's tableView when the save button pressed in my second view controller. How can I save this textfield datas to show in my tableView ?

I tried to write textfield datas to my local json file as below:

```
func writeToJSON() {
    let foo = Member(name: "Emre", age: 25, location: "Izmir", github: "emrdgrmnci", company: CompanyClass(position: "Software", years: 0))
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: foo, options: [])
        if let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("company.json")
            try data.write(to: fileUrl)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

What if I use `CoreData` to save my textfileds data and show in my another viewcontroller's tableView rows. Are they confuse with my local json file datas in tableview?

Comment: You will have to read the local json file into coredata and then show the data from coredata into the tableview. Then pass the list to second vc where you have textfields. Populate the textfields with passed data. And when save is clicked, you will have to save/update the changes into coredata. And when you come back to first vc, relaod the data such it reads the data again from coredata to update tableview data

Comment: Actually, I am adding new members to table view when save button clicked on the view controller which has the 6 textfields. Do you have any example link for saving json data to core data. First of all, I should save my json data to core data and after read from core data to populate my table view. And finally, also save text field datas to my core data and show in table view, right?

Comment: Yes. And you will get multiple sources when you search for parsing json and doing crud operations on coredata

Comment: There care many number of ways are there, you can use `delegates` or `NotificationCenter` or `CoreData` or `singleton` class what ever suitable to your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't be confused as long as you choose 1 source of truth of your data for your table (File Manager or Core Data). But if your local database and its objects relation inside are not complex, then FileManager should be enough. Seems the first view controller appear on the screen after save button pressed is like back button mechanism. You can use simple way by load the data from File Manager in viewWillAppear and call tableView.reloadData in viewWillAppear, but it's not so appropriate way to load data and populating tableView if not in viewDidLoad, so you can use NotificationCenter to notify the first view controller if there are changes on the data to reload data of the tableView

Edit: 
You can find way much more options to pass data between view controller, especially using Notification Center in here https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/#nsnotificationcenter

Comment: If you explain with code example I will accept your answer. I do not write code structure. Thank you so much